# Cannot connect to SQL Server Express 2014 from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

My question is regarding retrieving data from SQL Server (Express 2014) into Visual Studio (Professional 2012).  I am following a tutorial re usage of the drop down list. When I use 'Choose Data Source' I can proceed as far as selecting the database.  When I try to use 'Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)' and select 'NORTHWND.MDF' from my App_Data folder I get this error:

The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
an connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
allow remote connections (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error:50 - Local
Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows
Application event log for error details.)

I have nothing in the log re this.

When I try and connect to SQL Server using 'Microsoft SQL Server' I can get to the SQL Server Instance, select the database and get 'Connection Successful' but on OK get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version 11.0.0.0
Culture=neutral, Public Key Token=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.

I have installed SQLLocalDB.

Help greatly appreciated as this is holding up my studies.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

Comment: I have installed SSDT, but to be sure repaired it and rebooted... But still same issues. If it is of any relevance I also lack the option to link to MS-ACCESS, although that is installed on my machine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a message in the application event log which pointed out an incompatibility issue... I presumed this was between VS 2012 and SQL Server 2014. Accordingly I installed SQL Server 2012.  Subsequently running a 'Web Application' in VS 2012 I found that the 'Register' function in the automatically created page correctly created a user whereas previously it had failed with the error originally posted. I am assuming that all SQL Server related activities in VS 2012 will now work, but will report back here if I find otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

1. Open sql server management studio 2014
2. Right click on your database and select properties
3. Select permissions and select View Server Permissions link
4. Select the user name pc-name or current user name
5. Give permissions to connect and create databases

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install, LocalDB 64BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi, from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299.
2. Open an administrator command prompt and run -
   sqllocaldb create “v12.0″
3. Under Visual Studio menu items -> click on Tools -> Options -> Under the Database Tools node, choose Data Connections.
   Change SQL Server instance name to (LocalDB)\v12.0

Refer -
For SqlLocalDB Utility – http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx
For local database overview – http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx