# Unable to add data connection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2014, visual-studio-exp-2013

I have SQL Server 2014 installed. When I'm attempting to create a data connection within Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop it's giving me the below error.

> Unable to add data connection. Could not load file or assembly. `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[key]` or one of its `.dependancies`. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have downloaded and installed both the `.msi` files advised in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1) answer.

Although the answer states that with SQL Server 2014 you should receive the error message stating `Version=12.0.0.0`, however I'm receiving the error message showing `Version=11.0.0.0`. Should I maybe download and install the `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for SQL Server 2012?

Checking `C:\Windows\assembly` shows that `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc` is installed as version `12.0.0.0`.

Comment: Do you get that error during runtime or when you try to reference the assembly?

Comment: Once I've input the SQL Server name, and chosen the database name, I click 'Test Connection', which returns 'Test connection succeeded'. Then when pressing 'ok' to create the connection it throws the error detailed above. Thanks.

Comment: That's basically pinging the server and database to see if it's there when testing the connection. Are you including the username and password in the connection string?

Comment: I'm using Windows Authentication at present.

Comment: Alright take a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479366/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-express-2014-from-visual-studio-2012) it looks like you need to install the latest updates for the sql server tools.

Comment: Just downloaded and installed SQL Server database tools. Still getting the error described in my original post.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1) You may need to update your C++ redistributable pack. (link in question's accepted answer)

Comment: Again, no luck with that. I ended up downloading `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for SQL Server 2012 and this resolved the issue. No idea why I should be using Version 11 with SQL Server 2014, but at least it's now letting me create data connections. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi` for SQL Server 2012.

It would appear that when using Visual Studio 2013, and SQL Server 2014, it requires `version 11.0.0.0` of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc`.

Answer (score 1):

For both types (32 bit and 64 bit), this works:

1. Open URL `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580`
2. Download `ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi`
3. Download `ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi`
4. Install `ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi`
5. Install `ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi`
6. Restart your Visual Studio and now Everything will work smooth.

See [here](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1113/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc).